# Changing the MasterName during ActionFilter.OnResultExecuting throws exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an action filter that changes the master/layout page at runtime based on whether it is an ajax call. However it fires a System.Web.HttpException when it is an Ajax call.
This ActionFilter works fine with the WebForms engine but throw an exception with the razorengine.
The exception:

The "RenderBody" method has not been called for layout page "~/Views/xxxx/Empty.cshtml"

The action filter:

```
public class AjaxActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string MasterPage { get; set; }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != null
            && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
            if (viewResult != null)
            {
                viewResult.MasterName = MasterPage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Action is marked with this attribute as follows:

```
[AjaxActionFilter(MasterPage = "Empty")]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get), ActionName("Index"), CollectionAction]
public override ActionResult CollectionAction()
{
    ...
}
```

EDIT: and of course my layout view being Empty.cshtml is as follows:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="DefaultMasterHead">
       @RenderSection("styles", false)
    </head>
   <body>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
        @RenderSection("scripts", false)
    </body>
    </html>
```

If I hit the view with a non-Ajax call it is fine but if it is an Ajax call it throws the exception. Again, as I say it works correctly with the WebForms engine.

Can anyone explain what might be going on here?

TIA

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Sorry Josh, I haven't yet. Ironically I was trying out razor to try to work around another issue I had when upgrading to MVC3. I ended up just changing my WebForm views to workaround my original rendering issue. I haven't yet replicated it in a simple project. Cheers Simon.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding [OnActionExecuted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuted.aspx) instead of [OnResultExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onresultexecuting.aspx):

```
public class AjaxActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string MasterPage { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() && result != null)
        {
            result.MasterName = MasterPage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin,
this didn't work, so I think I will try and see if I can replicate it starting from an empty MVC project to rule out other interfering factors.
Cheers Simon